# Unable to perform click on the "PrestaShop" link in an IFrame like picture shown below

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, frame

Am having an issue where I need to perform a click using Selenium Java on the link "PrestaShop" shown below. It's in an IFrame and my code is also below the picture.

[Link to be clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Naaql.jpg)

When inspect the link using FireBug, it shows like below

[Inspect using FireBug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tPil.jpg)

And below is my code

```
try {
                List<WebElement> frames = getAllFrames();
                for (int i = 0; i < frames.size(); i++) {

                    WebElement frame = frames.get(i);
                    driver.switchTo().frame(frame);

                    if (driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@classname='_1drp _5lv6']/a")).getSize() != null) {
                        driver.findElement(By.className(".//*[@classname='_1drp _5lv6']/a")).click();
                    } else {
                        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                    }

                }
            } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
```

The code is getting all frames on the page and verify if the link "PrestaShop" is presence on the frame. If yes then it needs to fire a click on the link. Now, instead it returns error message - `Unable to locate element: .//*[@classname='_1drp _5lv6']/a`

Can please help to advise how can I fire the click successfully on the link?

Comment: simple.. In the if condition use driver.findElements instead of driver.findElement

Answer (score 0):

You can use following updated code:

```
 List<WebElement> frames = getAllFrames();
                for (int i = 0; i < frames.size(); i++) {

                    WebElement frame = frames.get(i);
                    driver.switchTo().frame(frame);

                    if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'PrestaShop')]")).getSize() != null) {
                        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'PrestaShop')]")).click();
                    } else {
                        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                    }

                }
            } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Hi RNS, I have tried with the code you suggested but unfortunately it's still giving me `Unable to locate element: .//*[@classname='_1drp _5lv6']/a`. Seems like the code fails at `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@classname='_1drp _5lv6']/a")).getSize() != null` and it never reach .click().

Answer (score 0):

While checking the presence of element, try using findElements instead of findElement. Below code might give you some idea.

```
            List<WebElement> frames = getAllFrames();
            for (int i = 0; i < frames.size(); i++) {

                WebElement frame = frames.get(i);
                driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
                //use driver.findElements
                if (driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@classname='_1drp _5lv6']/a")).getSize() != null) {
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'PrestaShop')]")).click();
                } else {
                    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                }

            }
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your comment. I realized its because of the FB link was loaded too slow and hence the code fails. It's able to click now with below code if I added a Thread.sleep(30000) there.

```
if (driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='lfloat']/div/a")).size() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Found elements.");
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'PrestaShop')]")).click();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Element not found.");
                    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                }
```

However, if I want a FluentWait, then below code will just stop if the condition was not met

```
if (wait.ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class).ignoring(TimeoutException.class)
                        .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@class='lfloat']/div/a")))
                        .isDisplayed()) {
                    System.out.println("Found elements.");
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'PrestaShop')]")).click();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Element not found.");
                    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                }
```

It just return message `Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: .//*[@class='lfloat']/div/a (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)` and then not continue the loop. Can I know what's the way to make the code to continue even if the condition was not met?